# nouislider events in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

I have implemented noui slider using this GIT:
    https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-nouislider

Slider is successfully implemented. Now I want to call a function on its slide event using AngularJS way of course.

I don't found any doc for that.

I found this sliders events in below link, but its jQuery version, how can I use such slider events in AngularJS way.

http://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/#section-binding

Here is my slider code:

```
<div slider ng-from="domainStrength.initial.start" ng-to="domainStrength.initial.end" start="{{ domainStrength.range.start}}" end="{{ domainStrength.range.end}}" step="{{ domainStrength.step}}" margin="{{ domainStrength.margin}}"></div>
```

And I want something like that:

```
<div slider ng-from="domainStrength.initial.start" ng-to="domainStrength.initial.end" start="{{ domainStrength.range.start}}" end="{{ domainStrength.range.end}}" step="{{ domainStrength.step}}" margin="{{ domainStrength.margin}}" onSlide="myCustomFun()"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, I'm able to use event by adding this: 
callback="change" change='{{ myCustom() }} in element tag
but upon page load, this myCustom() call for 11 times which should only call upon using slide

Answer (score 0):

*nouislider* directive listens on *slide* event for you (the event to which it listens can be changed though, *slide* is default) and updates your model values. If you want to detect and handle model change the angular way would be to set up watcher. Example:

```
app.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('test.single', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('Value has changed', newVal, oldVal);
    });

    $scope.$watchGroup(['test.from', 'test.to'], function (newVals, oldVals) {
        // NOTE: called whenever at least on of the watch values has changed
        console.log('From value', newVals[0], oldVals[0]);
        console.log('To value', newVals[1], oldVals[1]);
    });
});
```

Usage in template:

```
<div ng-controller="SimpleCtrl">
  <div slider ng-model="test.single" start="1" end="10"></div>
  <div slider ng-from="test.from" ng-to="test.to" start="0" end="100" step="5"></div>
</div>
```